# Python interpreter server similar to RServe

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, rserve

In R there's an [RServe](https://www.rforge.net/Rserve/faq.html) package which runs binary R server.

I can connect to it remotely, execute R commands and get structured output. Useful thing. I'm wondering if there's something similar in Python available.

I want to run Python interpreter on some remote server, connect to it, execute Python commands and get results back. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TabPy](https://github.com/tableau/TabPy) offers a similar REST interface.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Jupyter, particularly the Jupyter notebook server. Based on your question, this seems like the resource you need.

Though questions like this aren't really what StackOverflow is intended for, FYI.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for the general expectations.

"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thanks. Where is the place to ask these questions?

Comment: Checked Jupyter, similar but not exactly what I need. Jupyter seems GUI oriented but I need an API to pass Python code. Jupyter does have an API but it's not granular enough.